# cómo poner un máximo de caracteres en un título

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero poner un máximo de caracteres a un titulo, y cuando ya llegue a ese máximo muestre los 3 puntos que indican que el texto sigue, este es mi codigo:

```
.title {
font: bold 22px Roboto, sans-serif;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 8px 2px;
```

Comment: ¿Podrías indicarnos qué has intentado? El código solo es una clase en CSS sin cerrar.

Comment: Creo que no puedes limitar por el número de caracteres sino que debe ser por tamaño, al igual que te explican en la respuesta de J.Correa

Answer (score 3):

Usa propiedades de CSS

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .ellipsis {
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
     }
    .short { width: 50px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="short">
    <p class="ellipsis">Esto es una cadena muy larga</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando JavaScript, con .replace()

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName("title")].forEach(function(e){

e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace(/(.{1,5})(.*)/g, "$1...");

})
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Titulo muyyy largo</h1>
```